# Capitalization - heated debate on titles

Tags: capitalization

The capitalization in question is the following:

> The **first commander** wasn't happy with the decision you made.

Normally, if I was to swap it out for something like "Dad" it would be capitalized, but the research I've done says do **not** capitalize the ***f*** or ***c***.

But some have gotten heated saying you would because it is referring to a person. However, in other circumstances, president in the same sentence would not be.

What should happen here?

Answer (score 4):

Proper nouns are capitalized. Common nouns are not.

If "first commander" take the place of a name and refers to a unique individual (like "Commander-in-Chief"), it's a proper noun and would be capitalized. If refers to a member of a larger class (like "second lieutenant"), it would not be.

Another way to think about it is to ask: could you say "**a** first commander", or is it only possible to say "**the** First Commander". In the first case it's a common noun, in the second a proper noun.

Comment: *“Did you tell First Commander about this yet?”* The [distinctive **grammatical** properties of proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) are far more interesting than their merely orthographic properties de jour.

Comment: The use of the definite article is ***not*** what determines if it's a proper noun or not. In fact, most (although not all) proper nouns are *not* preceded by *the*.

Comment: @JasonBassford You're entirely correct. What I was trying to say is that proper nouns *sometimes* have definite articles, but *never* have indefinite articles.

Comment: Very off-topic but proper nouns can have indefinite articles when they denote a class of things that can be identified by the same proper noun, e.g. "There is not one shred of secular evidence there ever was a Jesus Christ" or "The theatre producer is searching for a Hamlet for a new production".